# catching "socket.timeout The read operation timed out" in python

Tags: python, sockets, exception

I'm making calls to an API and am receiving the following timeout error:

```
socket.timeout The read operation timed out
```

which traces back from

```
File "/Users/someuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Users/someuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Users/someuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Users/someuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Users/someuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 937, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Users/someuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 799, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/Users/someuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 583, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout The read operation timed out
```

How can I catch this error from the top of the traceback?

Answer (score 11):

This is a duplicate question, however the correct approach is to catch `socket.timeout` by using

```
import socket
try:
    ...
except socket.timeout:
    ...
```

The error states the exception that was thrown explicitly and you can rely on that. Even though the calling method is the ssl lib, the error seems to be related to the actual socket connection.

Comment: This works very well. Please don't forget to add the import statement for socket before.

Answer (score 0):

Google search led to me https://community.home-assistant.io/t/difficulty-catching-an-exception/12955/6

It seems like SSL throws `ssl.SSLError` when it times out. You could try something like:

```
import ssl

def getresponse():
     ...
     try:
          response.begin
     except ssl.SSLError as err:
          handle_error(err)
```